# Different Seek Pointer for read\write

Tags: c, linux, file, inode

I am trying to understand how the seek pointer mechanism works when a parent process opens a new file and then creating a new child process using `fork()`.

Assume I have the following code :

```
int main(){
int fd = open("myFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT)
if(fork() == 0){
 write(fd,"stack overflow", 16);
 close(fd);
}
else{
 wait(NULL);
 char buff[17];
 read(fd, &buff, 16);
 printf("%s", buff);
}
```

}

I get nothing printing to stdout, but I don't really understand why would it behave that way. Wouldn't it be smarter if there were a different seek pointer for read and write so running this code will result in printing "stack overflow" to stdout?

Apparently not, Would like to get an explanation

Comment: "*Wouldn't it be smarter*". According to who? The behaviour you have found is correct as defined by [fork](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html): *"The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
          descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the
          same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding
          file descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two file
          descriptors share open file status flags, file offset, and
          signal-driven I/O attributes"*

Comment: One big problem is that your code doesn't check what `read` *returns*. That could make you attempt to print the *uninitialized* data in the array `buff` and that could lead to *undefined behavior*. Another problem is if `read` is successful then you don't add the null-terminator which means you *again* have undefined behavior as the `printf` function can go out of bounds when looking for it. Also, you should not use the pointer-to operator in the `read` call, but use plain `buff` (which will *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array).

Comment: No two programs step in the same stream - Heraclitus

Comment: `write(fd,"stack overflow", 16);` attempts to write 16 bytes from an array which contains only 15 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both processes are using the *same* file description (i.e. the same open file).

They are accessing the same file pointer because it's part of the same file description. When one of them writes some characters, the file pointer advances for all of them, because it's the same file pointer.

You can get the file pointer by calling `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)`. If you print the file pointer before starting the child program, and after waiting for it, you should see that it has changed.